# Extracting a value from a reference string with simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, regex, parsing, simple-html-dom

I need to extract the value `3899461` from a string like this one

```
<script data-config=\"\/\/config.playwire.com\/14907\/videos\/v2\/3899461\/zeus.json\
```

This piece of code is extracted from a web page, and it is part of a longer line. By using Simple HTML DOM Parser, is it possible to extract just that value by finding the only recurrence of this particular line?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So the main problem is that the string is inside a `<script type="text/javascript">` element and I don't know who to select the innertext of this element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `THIS_NUMBER` is indeed a number, and not a string; the following would work:

```
preg_match(
    '~<script data-config="//config\.playwire\.com/14907/videos/v2/(\d+)/zeus.json"~',
    $yourWholeHTMLPage,
    $matches
);
```

Comment: It does not work, and yes it is a number, like for example 3900186

Comment: The `$yourWholeHTMLPage`, in my case, is the result of this `$ch = curl_init();
   $timeout = 0; 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
   $file_contents = curl_exec($ch); 
   $html = str_get_html($file_contents);` where `$url` is the right web address, and I pass to `preg_match` the value `$html`

Comment: @Sfrow The results would be stored in `$matches`. Add a `var_dump($matches)` after the above code.

Comment: I know, no results in fact. That's the result: `array(0) { } `

Comment: Can you put the relevant section of your `$html` as is (without any edits) in your question? Use `var_dump` and your browser's _Find in page_ features.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    DataStore['categoryId'] = 8;
    DataStore['daysSincePosted'] = 2;
    VideoSelector.load([{"index":0,"type":"full","label":"Full Highlights","payloadType":"html","payload":"<script data-config=\"\/\/config.playwire.com\/14907\/videos\/v2\/3899461\/zeus.json\" data-css=\"\/\/cdn.playwire.com\/bolt\/js\/zeus\/skins\/default.css\" data-height=\"100%\" data-width=\"100%\" src=\"\/\/cdn.playwire.com\/bolt\/js\/zeus\/embed.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"><\/script>"}]);
   </script>`